# When is $\mathrm{Proj}(A)$ projective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

We consider the scheme $P:=\mathrm{Proj}(S)$ of a commutative, (nonnegatively) graded, finitely generated $\mathbb C$-algebra $S$ with no nilpotents.

**(Q1) When is $P$ a projective variety?**

Since we have a projective map $P \to \mathrm{Spec}(S_0)$, $P$ is projective if $S_0=\mathbb C$. But the opposite direction is too difficult for me. (I have neither a proof nor a counterexample.)

**(Q2) Is $P$ always quasi-projective?**

The examples which I know are always quasi-projective, so I suspect that $P$ is always quasi-projective, but I can not find any relevant references.

**EDIT** (An example of non-projective $P$)

Let $G = \lbrace \mathrm{diag}(t,t^{-1},u) \in GL_3(\mathbb C) | t \in \mathbb C^*, u = \pm 1 \rbrace$ act on $\mathbb C^3$ and define a character of $G$ by $\chi(t,t^{-1},u)=tu$. The character defines a $G$-equivariant line budle $L \to \mathbb C^3$. Put $$S_* = \bigoplus_{d\geq0}H^0(\mathbb C^3,L^{\otimes d})^G.$$ We can show that $S_*$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb C$-algebra (e.g. [Lemma 14.1.10](https://books.google.de/books?id=AoSDAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA682&vq=GIT%20Quotients&hl=de&pg=PA682#v=onepage&q&f=false)) and 
$$S_{2*} = \bigoplus_{d} S_{2d} = \mathbb C[xy,z^2][x^2].$$
Therefore
$$\mathrm{Proj}(S_*) = \mathrm{Proj}(S_{2*}) = \mathrm{Proj}(\mathbb C[xy,z^2][x^2]) = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb C[xy,z^2]) \times \mathbb P^0 = \mathbb C^2.$$

Note: This example can be found the book linked above (in Chap. 14).

Answer (score 2):

This answer your question just partially.

Let $S=\oplus_{n=0}^\infty S_n$ be a finitely generated graded $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and consider the graded $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $S'$ defined by $S_0'=\mathbb{C}$ and $S_n'=S_n$ for $n>0$. Then there exists an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-schemes $\operatorname{Proj}(S)\cong\operatorname{Proj}(S')$ (EGA II, 2.4.8). Therefore if $S'$ is finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra then $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ is projective.

However the condition on $S'$ of being finitely generated is not necessary because of the following: For $d>0$, let $S'^{(d)}$ be the graded $\mathbb{C}$-algebra defined by $S'^{(d)}_n=S'_{nd}$ for $n\geq 0$. Then there exists an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-schemes $\operatorname{Proj}(S')\cong\operatorname{Proj}(S'^{(d)})$ (EGA II, 2.4.7).

Then we can conclude that if for some $d>0$ the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $S'^{(d)}$ is finitely generated then $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ is a projective variety.

For an example where $\operatorname{Proj}(S)$ is not a projective variety, I would try with $S=\mathbb{C}[X][Y]=\oplus_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{C}[X]Y^n$. Not that in this case none of the $S'^{(d)}$ are finitely generated. I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: In your example, the global sections are $\mathbb C[X]$, no?, so it cannot be projective.

Comment: @Diego Thanks for your answer. I added a possible counterexample to my question. I am confused now. But I should say that the finitely generated property could not be relevant, as you say. (I do not have any reason why we should assume it. It is just in case.)

Comment: I am also confused. If $S$ is finitely generated with $S_0=\mathbb{C}$, some of the $S^{(d)}$ is generated in degree 1 (take $d$ as the lcm of the degrees of the generators) and therefore $S^{(d)}$ is a quotient of some $\mathbb{C}[X_0,\ldots,X_n]$ and therefore $Proj(S)$ is a closed subscheme of $P_{\mathbb{C}}^n$.